# Get local variable from ssh call in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a script called `global.sh` which copies a shell script called `my_local_script.sh` on a remote machine.

```
scp my_local_script.sh host@user_a:remote_directory
```

Then i connect to that ssh host and execute it like this

```
ssh host@user "
                cd remote_directory
                ./my_local_script.sh
              "
```

So far so good and everything is ok, the problem is that i want to get a local variable inside `my_local_script.sh` to `global.sh`. I tried doing this

```
ssh host@user "
                cd remote_directory
                my_arg=$(./my_local_script.sh)
              "
```

But this does not work and the even the call of my local script does not work properly anymore. Any suggestions how can i overcome this issue.

PS : Copying the variable to a temporary file is not an option. I am looking for a shell solution for this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a command substitution, which is necessary, but it is in the wrong place. You should place it around the entire SSH command:

```bash
my_var=$(ssh host@user "cd remote_directory; ./my_local_script.sh")
```

This is assuming that the variable you want to capture is being outputted by my_local_script eg by `echo` or `printf`.